# Moment.js week number differs from MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, date, momentjs, iso8601

From the [docs for Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/), it says `moment().startOf('isoWeek')` sets to the first day of the week according to ISO 8601.

From the [wikipedia page for ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates), it says the first week is (among other equivalent definitions): the first week with the majority (four or more) of its days in the starting year.

From the [docs for MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week), it says `WEEK(date, 3)` gives a week (1-53) with Monday as the first day of the first week with 4 or more days this year.

From what I can tell, these are all equivalent definitions of a week, yet they don't mesh.

My MySQL database (v5.6.17) gives me `201616` for `SELECT YEARWEEK('2016-4-20',3)`

Using Moment.js (v2.10.3) in the browser gives me `Mon Apr 11 2016` for `moment().year(2016).week(16).startOf("isoweek")`

Those aren't the same week, and I can't figure out why.

Comment: 11 April 2016 is indeed the ISO start of the 15th week of 2016, and 20 April is in the 16th (though Monday 18 is the ISO start of that week). I think your syntax is wrong: `moment('2016-W16')` sets a date for 2016-04-18, which is Monday at the start of the 16th week.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `.week()` you are setting the "locale" week (I have no idea how moment.js works that out), but likely the first day will be Sunday. When you then call `.startOf('isoweek')` you are then getting the ISO start of that week, which is the previous Monday.

If you want to use ISO, you have to use ISO methods, so:

```
moment().year(2016).isoWeek(16).startOf('isoweek');
```

creates a moment object for 2016-04-18T00:00:00

Or use a string:

```
moment('2016-W16') // 2016-04-18T00:00:00
```

which defaults to ISO week numbering and start of week.

Comment: Should you not be setting `isoWeekYear` rather than `year`? As the ISO year could be 2015 at the start of 2016, for example.

Comment: @Brendon—I don't know why the OP was setting the year, I was just pointing out the differences. Setting *isoWeekYear* sets the day to the same day in the equivalent week of the year. Around 1 Jan it can shift the date by about 12 months, e.g. `moment('2016-01-01').isoWeekYear(2016).format()` gives 2016-12-30, since Fri 1 Jan 2016 was in ISO week 53 of 2015 and setting the ISO year 2016 shifts it to Fri in week 53 of 2016, which is 30 Dec 2016.

Comment: I don't know what the OPs intentions are either, but he mentioned the `YEARWEEK` function from MySQL, so presumably he is interested in setting the weekYear rather than the year. Even if the OP wasn't using the ISO standard week years & week numbers, he would need to use moment#weekYear rather than moment#year.